# HTML pattern regex for no spaces

Tags: html, regex

What will be the correct regex pattern for an HTML input which should allow only  Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_. No spaces.

Answer (score 12):

You can use this regex for no space:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="[^' ']+" />
  <input type="submit" value="test submit">
</form>
```

So you can modify it to add your other rules

Comment: `pattern="[^\s]+"` if you don't want any white space

Answer (score 1):

If characters order and count does not matter you can use this:

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9@\.+_]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Scratch that, there's actually a regex for that.

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^\S+$">
```

That would work for `MyName`, but not for `My Name`.